# Java - random space after components

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am currently making a Twitter client, and I found some issue I couldn't solve myself.
I'm not sure what part of the code should I include, so I'll post a picture.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrCi0.png)

I have a JPanel in a JScrollPane, and then I add small JPanels (the tweets) to that JPanel. But there's always a space after those components.
Any advice about where is that space came from?
Thank You in advance.
Here are some pieces of code:

This is the main JPanel, that handles the Tweet JPanels:

```java
package net.rothens.twitt3ns.gui;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.swing.*;
import net.rothens.twitt3ns.Twitt3ns;
import twitter4j.Status;

/**
 *
 * @author Rothens
 */
public class TweetsPanel extends JPanel {

public java.util.List<Long> timestamps;

public TweetsPanel() {
    initUI();
}

public final void initUI() {
    timestamps = new ArrayList<Long>();
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
}

public void addTwitt(Status s) {
    if (!Twitt3ns.tw.mw.isScrollbarOnTop()) {
        Twitt3ns.tw.mw.saveScrollbarPosition();
    }
    int pos = getPos(s.getCreatedAt().getTime()) + 1;
    TweetPanel tp = new TweetPanel(s);
    if (pos >= getComponentCount()) {
        add(tp);
    } else {
        add(tp, pos);
    }

    validate();
    if (!Twitt3ns.tw.mw.isScrollbarOnTop()) {
        Twitt3ns.tw.mw.loadScrollbarPosition(tp.getHeight());
    }
}

/**
 * Update the time on the panels
 */
public void updatePanels() {
    for (Component c : getComponents()) {
        if (c instanceof TweetPanel) {
            ((TweetPanel) c).updateTime();
        }
    }
    validate();

}


/**
 * Gets the position of a new tweet
 * @param what the time when the new component was created
 * @return position of the new component
 */
public int getPos(long what) {
    timestamps.add(what);
    Collections.sort(timestamps);
    return timestamps.size() - timestamps.indexOf(what) - 2;

}

public TweetsPanel(int id) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            TweetsPanel tl = new TweetsPanel();
            tl.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

The Tweet JPanels code is this (I'll post in pastebin, it's way too big) : [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/gYmVctfd)

And in the Main JFrame, I create the tabbed pane, and the ScrollPanes in this way:

```java
 tabPane.setTabPlacement(javax.swing.JTabbedPane.BOTTOM);
 tabPane.setAlignmentX(0.0F);
 tabPane.setAlignmentY(0.0F);

 spHome.setAlignmentX(0.0F);
 spHome.setAlignmentY(0.0F);
 spHome.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
 tabPane.addTab("Otthon", spHome);
 tabPane.addTab("@", null, spMention, "Tweetek amik Téged említenek");
```

And this is how I add the JPanels to the JScrollPanes:

```java
tpHome.setBorder(null);
tpHome.setFocusable(false);
spHome.setViewportView(tpHome);

tpMention.setBorder(null);
tpMention.setFocusable(false);
spMention.setViewportView(tpMention);
```

Comment: Show us the code where you create and add the panel in the scroll pane. Are you settings it's size anywhere?

Comment: It will be very hard to track down the problem without any source code. You should at least describe the setup of your view...which layout do you use etc. Most likely some code will be necessary to help you.

Comment: okay, just a minute, and I'll add :)

Comment: What are the borders set to on your panels? By default, JPanels have a couple of pixels left blank as a border, from what I recall.

Comment: @mcfinnigan they are all set to null, except the small TweetPanel, which has an EtchedBorder